# Correct way of calculating modularity for weighted graphs

Tags: r, igraph

I have about 13000 genes which I am trying to cluster using igraph as follows:

```
g.communities <- edge.betweenness.community(as.undirected(g), weights = E(g)$weight)
```

which returns 97 communities with modularity 0.9773353:

```
 modularity(as.undirected(g), membership = g.communities$membership, weights = E(g)$weight)
 
 #0.9773353
```

when I tried to custom made the number of communities as below I get modularity of 0.0094:

```
 modularity(as.undirected(g), membership = cutat(g.communities, steps = 97), weights = 
 E(g)$weight)
 
 #0.0094
```

Shouldn't these functions return similar results? Also, is it possible to use the above
function to find the correct number of clusters? (since by just increasing the steps the modularity always increases)

Finally g.communities$modularity returns a number for each vertex.
Can these numbers be interpreted as the correlation of each vertex to its corresponding module?

Comment: At this time, do not use `edge.betweenness.community` for weighted graphs. See what I wrote here: https://igraph.discourse.group/t/output-igcommunitiesedgebetweenness/822 Unweighted is fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `steps` argument of `cut_at`. This does not specify the number of communities, but the number of merging steps to perform on the dendrogram. If you want 97 communities, use `cut_at(g.communities, no=97)` or simply `cut_at(g.communities, 97)`.

---

That said, I do not suggest using `edge.betweenness.community` on weighted graphs at this time, for the reasons I described [here](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/output-igcommunitiesedgebetweenness/822).

Comment: You are right!! no=97 fixes the problem! So except edge.betweenness.community there is no other alternative function for weighted graphs? Also, any ideas regarding g.communities$modularity and what it represents?

Comment: @pridu Several of the community detection functions support weighted graphs. Why do you want to use `edge.betweenness.community`? It's not a very good method anyway.

Comment: `g.communities$modularity` represents the modularity score at each possible cut of the dendrogram.

Comment: I want to use g.communities$modularity return as an index of how well correlated is a node inside a cluster. I have started with Louvain but in this case g.communities$modularity returns only 4 numbers. The only method that seems to return one metric for each vertex is edge.betweenness.community. I also needed to use an hierarchical algorithm so to play with the cut_at. For a somewhat bigish weighted net such as this what algorithms would you propose?

Comment: No, `g.communities$modularity` does _not_ contain a value for each vertex. The meaning of this vector is what I said in my comment above. I'm sorry, I cannot give you a comment-size advice on how to measure "how well correlated is a node inside a cluster" (in fact it's not even clear what you mean by this).

Comment: Another reason I abandoned Louvain is that it returns almost 200 communities with 98% modularity. Does this seem correct? For example, if I force to have 400 communities then my modularity would be even higher!! On the other hand, edge.betweenness.community with cut_at no>23 returns a modularity  which is almost stable (96-98%). So, do I follow edge.betweenness and use around 23 communities, or Louvain and use 200?